# What blocks can Experience Orbs travel through?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw just now that the Orbs travel through closed doors. What else do they go through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XP orbs can **not** travel through anything solid (even closed doors) unless you get close enough, and if you get close enough then they'll go through anything. There is not a specific list of things that they can and cannot travel through.